# Remove hidden CR and or LF's in Byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, decode

Following is a code excerpt from a C# network class that decodes a TCP Socket message.
I assume the reason I don't see the 2nd trace is because there are 1 or more invisible CR's or LF's in the data object.
Is there some way of showing these and or removing them so I can reach my 2nd trace?

```
// Get a stream object for reading and writing
stream = client.GetStream();
int i;
// Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
{
    data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);

    //1st trace, I see TRIGGER
    Debug.Log("0 ASSERT Received: data = " + data );
    switch (data)
    {
        case "TRIGGER":
        //Don't see this trace!
        Debug.Log(":1 ASSERT TRIGGER RECEIVED");

//etc, etc
```

Comment: Does `Replace` not work for you?

Comment: CR or LF will not make the output not visible, it will add a new line, maybe there are some null chars `'\0'`?

Comment: Have you set a break point to make sure the case is being hit as expected?  "TRIGGER" is not the same as "TRIGGER " or "Trigger" - you may want to `switch (data.Trim().ToUpper())` to improve your odds, especially if you don't have control of the code on the other end of the socket...

Comment: Your assumption makes this seem kinda XY problem-ish.. Are you *sure* that's the issue?

Comment: There is some logic problem in your code: You can never be sure that each read on Tcp client side corresponds to each write on TcpServer server side, e.g. a single write may result in 2 consecutive read or 2 write may be got by a single read.

Comment: You could check to see if your data contains ascii chars 10 or 13 (linefeed or carriage return decimal values respectively) (10 = 0A hex, 13 = 0D hex) to see if that's in fact the problem.